Scanner is unaffected by colour profiles and contrast
I am using Simple Scan and a CanoScan LiDE 30 scanner on my Ubuntu machine. So far I only needed to scan documents, but recently decided to start scanning photos too. Unfortunately the color reproduction is off and I need to tweak the scanner parameters.
I tried the basic brightness and contrast in Simple Scan, but only brightness did something. I tried the same using scanimage, but the result remained the same. I then tried to load a custom color profile (via the colour management settings) for a different canon scanner, but it likewise did not change the scanner output.
Am I doing something wrong so that the colour profile isn't applied? Or is the scanner maybe not fully supported?

I would go with the second choice. The scanner can not do what you want it to do.
